# How can I use transition on individual list elements in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My understanding of transitions in vue.js is that you use `<transition>`
to animate between individual elements and `<transition-group>` to animate a whole list.

It seems as though if you wanted to animate a transition within a list item you'd use `<transition>` within the list. e.g. something like this:

```
<span v-for="item in items">
  <transition>

    <div>
        Transition from this...
    </div>

    <div>
         ...to this.
    </div>

  </transition>
</span>
```

Yet, when I make that change the animation doesn't work. Is this an expected behavior?

**Update**: after some tinkering, I have found that my original hypothesis was correct. I was just doing something else wrong. But it's worth noting for anyone else who comes across this problem.

You can use `<transition>` inside a list if you want to animate individual components of the list.

Comment: I think your first line is the answer :) If you are animating a list of items, go for `transition-group`.

Comment: did you try this https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Move-Transitions

Comment: Yes, the issue is that _transition groups_ are for animating lists. But _transition_ is for animating individual elements. So if I want to animate a single element within a list then what do i use? I can't find any documentation with a transition inside a v-for loop.

Answer (score 2):

You use transition groups to transition all children in the same way.
In addition, try setting the transition group before your `v-for`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items : [
      {message: 'sometext', id: 1},
      {message: 'sometext', id: 2},
      {message: 'sometext', id: 3}
     ],
     id : 3
  },
  methods: {
    addItem(){
            this.id++
            this.items.push({message: 'sometext', id: this.id});
        },
     enter(){
         console.log('transition enter called');
     }
  }
})
```

```css
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="container">
        <button @click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
        <transition-group :name="'fade'" v-on:enter="enter">
            <span v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item.id">
               {{item.message}}
            </span>
        </transition-group>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do with your example.

If you would like to transition a list

```
  <transition-group name="fade" tag="span">
    <div v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item">
      {{ item }}
    </div>
  </transition-group>
```

If you would like to transition between two items.

```
  <transition name="fade">
    <div v-show="whatever === true">
      Transition from this...
    </div>
  </transition>
  <transition name="fade">
    <div v-show="whatever === false">
     ...to this.
    </div>
  </transition>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is correct, my issue was with using <transition> inside a list.

Comment: Transitioning between two items should be done with a single transition wrapper around elements with if/else statements (only one element can be rendered at a time) and using either mode out-in or in-out. out-in transitions the first element out first and in-out transitions the new element in first.