# Animating duplicate list items added with v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs-transition-group

I want to animate list items in a loop with vue's transition group. I want always the added item to be animated. But I always got the last one animated. Research in docs/questions indicated this normally is a keying problem: Key needs unique id. Now I can't take the IDs from the array I'm outputting there, as I'm outputting *randomly*, so keys would be duplicate (actually I get a duplicate elements console error).

So I built on [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54063479/10848966) to get a unique id.

script:

```
data: function() {
       return {
       logId: 1,
       },

methods: {
randomize () {
        if (this.activeAudio) {
          this.pause();
          this.activeAudio = null;
        }
        var chosenNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.audios.length);
        this.activeAudio = this.audios[chosenNumber];
        this.activeAudio.isPlaying = true;
        this.activeAudio.file.play();
        this.activeAudio.file.loop = true;
        this.audioLogItems.unshift({
            text: this.activeAudio.name
        });

        this.logId++;
        this.audioLogItems.push({id: this.logId});
       },
}
```

template:

```
<transition-group name="baseLogList" tag="ul">
                    <li v-for="(audioLogItem, id) in audioLogItems" 
                    :key="id"
                    @click="this.audioLogItem.file.play()">
                      {{ audioLogItem.text }}
                    </li> 
                  </transition-group>
```

CSS:

```
.baseLogList {
  display:block
}
.baseLogList-enter-active, .baseLogList-leave-active {
  transition: all .5s;
}
.baseLogList-enter, .baseLogList-leave-to /* .fade-in-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Outputting   {{ audioLogItem.id }} instead of {{ audioLogItem.text }} actually gives me 2, 3, 4 and so on each click. But it doesn't seem it can be used in the loop, as still always the last children gets animated, not the first.

**My question: How can I manage to always get the added item to be animated, so the first one in the list?**

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing at the end of the `audioLogItems` array.

If you want to see the first element being animated, you need to push it at the head of the array.

Try to use [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift).

```
this.audioLogItems.unshift({id: this.logId});
```

Comment: This works for the ids, the last one is added at the top of the log. But still the first id at the list bottom gets animated every time >.<. Also, I don't want to display the ids, but the output text. Output text is still added at the end - although added with unshift as well...